# Question about space of sequences.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the complex linear spaces $l_{1}, l_{\infty }$ and the subspace $c_{0}$ of $l_{\infty }$ sequences consisting of $\left ( x_{n} \right )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0}=0.$

Show that:

a) $c_{0}^{*}=l_{1}$

b) $l_{1}^{*}=l_{\infty }$

I've already tried to solve it a number of ways, but I do not understand this issue very well.

thanks for any help

Comment: There're directions in the FAQ section for using LaTeX in this site to properly write mathematics.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried at least.